# FirebaseVision, ML Kit FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer CUSTOM MODEL OCR for Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, ocr

I'm working on some prototype for reading very specific text (OCR). It's obvious that on the Internet there are so many examples etc, but so far I'm not able for find any useful information for my case. Everything is too general for me. I don't want to spend moths for studying :) So that's how it looks like in this moment:

1. The ML Kit on device doesn't work for my case.
2. I've build a trainer to train my own custom models using python and Keras. In the end of process I've got .tflite model.
3. I want to use it in my Android app. So my first approach was to use ML Kit and custom models. But ... it's made for image recognition (detecting things in the image, not the text)

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-android-custom-model/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

I'm not able to find any example for using custom model for text recognition (on device solution)

**So the question nr1 is**: Is it possible to use ML Kit with custom models for text recognition ? From: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text I can conclude that custom models "on device" are supported only for classification and object recognition, in other cases I'm forced to use "on cloud" solution ?

If that's right then from the other hand we've got something like this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/text/FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer
I conclude it can support "on device" solution, but there are no functions for passing custom models, so I'm totally confused. Maybe "on device" means on on device compute, not on device model...

**The question nr2 is**: is there any relatively simple solution for this problem, some examples of how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for Q1:** No custom model is not currently supported by Text Recognition API for both [on-device ML Kit solution](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/android) or [on-cloud Firebase ML solution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/android/recognize-text).

**Answer for Q2:** This depends on the failure mode of how the Text Recognition is not picking it up. Here are some examples from the most trivial to more advance:

1. Text are recognised with typo - For example, text recognition on expiry date on a tin can may mix up the word June "JUN" with "JUH". If the vocabulary you are trying to detect is limited and the mistake is highly repeatable, a simple String map look up maybe sufficient to correct the spelling.
2. The text areas are detected but the recognition is wrong - You can use ML Kit Text Recognition API to tell you the areas of text and then use your own custom model for recognition.
3. The text area is not detected - I'm afraid the current ML Kit solution cannot help in this case.

In all cases, please file a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=897785&template=1457144) if the language is a latin-based language. If it is a non latin-based language, that will fall under [enhancement request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=897785&template=1457328).

Also check out the [new Digital Ink Recognition API](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/digital-ink-recognition/android) if the input can be from the user's drawing on the screen rather than a static picture.